# Retrieve Html Control Value in other Classes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an element like this in **Default.aspx** :

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfID" runat="server" />
```

And now I need to retrieve this element value in another class like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Sample001 {
    public class SlaveValue {
        public void RetrieveValue() {
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Edit:

It's some complicated, I add value to element inside of jQuery Script and when the request of jQuery Ajax send I need this value in HttpHandler to response correctly.

Comment: when do u want to do that in postback?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Store it somewhere else. I don't recommend putting on session since this would break your separation of concerns but perhaps your class is meant to be used only inside this web app. If that's the case, Session is probably the best candidate.

You could do

```
 HttpContext.Current.Session["key"] = ...
```

Comment: It's some complicated, I add value to element inside of jQuery Script and when the request of jQuery Ajax send I need this value in HttpHandler to response correctly

Answer (score 0):

Pass a reference of your Page instance to the class. Then you should be able to access the value as `myPageReference.hfID.Value`.

Comment: Yeah, but he's probably on need of this because he needs to access this value from a *different* page

Comment: @Icarus: Might be. With the information he provided, it's almost impossible to tell (SlaveValue does not derive from Page).

Answer (score 0):

when do u want to do that?is it in postback? 
then you can pass the page to this class constructor so you can access to page controls via FindControl method

Pageisntance.FindControl('controlid')

Comment: He could just pass the value if that was the case

Comment: hmm I actually do in httpHandler for handle jQuery Ajax request

Answer (score 0):

After reading  @Saeid saying "I actually do in httpHandler for handle jQuery Ajax request", you could just pass the hidden field as a query string (assuming its a get method) and access it in your handler using the httpcontext object, for e.g. context.Request.Params["HiddenValue"]. Hope this helps.